# Select rows with id larger then lowest id from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I want to get `logId`, `userId`, `updated`, `updatedById` where `logId` is larger then the lowest `logId` found for this `userId`.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT logId, userId, updated, updatedById
FROM users_updatelog
WHERE userid=548
) AS tbl1 
WHERE (tbl1.logId > (SELECT MIN(tbl1.logId) FROM tbl1))
ORDER BY tbl1.updated DESC
```

But this is not right. I can't query from the subqueried table tbl1 (error message: Invalid object name 'tbl1')

Any tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT logId, userId, updated, updatedById
FROM users_updatelog
WHERE userid = 548
AND logId > (SELECT min(logId) FROM users_updatelog WHERE userid = 548)
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT logId, userId, updated, updatedById
FROM users_updatelog
WHERE userid=548
AND logId > (SELECT MIN(logId) FROM users_updatelog WHERE userid=548)
ORDER BY updated DESC
```